# Differentiate using limit definition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

$f(x,y)=x^2y^2$, $a=(2,-1)$

So I'm using this definition:

$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\Vert f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h\Vert}{\Vert h\Vert}=0
$$

I get 
$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{\Vert (2+h_1)^2(h_2-1)^2-4(1)-4h_1+8h_2\Vert}{\Vert h\Vert}\\
=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}
\frac{\vert 4h_2^2+4h_2^2h_1-8h_1h_2-2h_1^2h_2+h_1^2h_2^2+h_1^2\vert}{\Vert h\Vert}
$$

I know I want to use squeeze theorem somehow but the quotient I have looks pretty useless right now.

Comment: which variable are you trying to differentiate with respect to?

Comment: I'm trying to show its totally differentiable at a.

Comment: I believe that when you expanded the second line to get the third you made some mistakes.

Comment: Ok I fixed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these inequalities: 
\begin{align*} 
&h_1^2 \le h_1^2 +  h_2^2 = \|h\|^2\\
&h_2^2\le h_1^2+ h_2^2 \le \| h\|^2\\
& |h_1 h_2| \le \frac 12 (h_1^2 + h_2^2) = \frac 12 \|h\|^2
\end{align*} 
The sum you have in numerator is therefore bounded above by 
$$4\|h\|^2 + 2|h_2| \|h\|^2+ 4 \|h\|^2+|h_1| \|h\|^2+\frac 14 \|h\|^2 + \|h\|^2,$$
dividing by $\|h\|$, the whole thing goes to zero as $\|h\|\to 0$.